# Automatically update created_by and updated_by value in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to add the current user_id into a created_by or updated_by field automatically.
But I can't seem to get the current user_id into the entity of the other table.
I'm using FOSUserBundle....

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setCreatedByValue()
{
    if(!$this->getCreatedBy())
    {
        $user= $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $this->created_by = $user->getId();
    }
}
```

This throws a Undefined property: ..... Container error :-(

How do I access the current user id?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entity does not have any reference to the container. Where is this `$this->container` coming from ? From nowhere.

There would many ways to resolve the problems, but it's better to implement what you need than fixing your problems :)

So I would suggest a Doctrine listener, that would modify the `createdBy` value every time an entity is created.

In fact, it already exist: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#blameable

Take a look at implementation: https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/src/Knp/DoctrineBehaviors/ORM/Blameable/BlameableListener.php#L151

Comment: i'm not very experienced with symfony. just seems to complicated for me :-)

Comment: This is more a Doctrine problem. There is no simpler way. If you really want to have a ccess to the container in your entity, it's even more complicated.

Comment: although, there's already a UserActionListener which handles logging and stuff. can i just add that prePersist function there?

Comment: You can follow the exact same rules for a more specific listener. Or you can add it in this existing one, yes!

Comment: alright, and then what do i have to to in the entity's setCreatedByValue() function? nothing?